# Why webelement list size shows 0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I would like to more about selenium webdriver java
`

```
package pkg;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
public class Booking {
    
    ChromeDriver driver;
    String baseurl="https://www.expedia.co.in/Flights";
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        }

    @Test
    public void functions() throws InterruptedException  {
          driver.get(baseurl); 
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement dropdown=  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Economy']"));
dropdown.click();
List <WebElement> drop=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='uitk-list uitk-type-400']//span"));
for(int i=0;i<drop.size();i++) 
{
    System.out.println(drop.get(i).getText());
    if(drop.get(i).getText().contains("First class")) {
        drop.get(i).click();
        break; }  }
WebElement from=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Leaving from']"));
from.sendKeys("Brussels (BRU - All Airports) Belgium");
List<WebElement> lists=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='origin_select-menu']/section/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[@data-stid='origin_select-result-item']"));
System.out.println("Size:" +lists.size());
Thread.sleep(2000);
//driver.quit();


}
}
```

I am trying to test the expedia.co.in website.where i want to test leaving from field and want to pass a value and also i want select that particular value from the auto suggestion list

Answer (score 0):

1.Use explicit waits to wait for the suggestions to appear before trying to select one. This ensures the DOM is ready before interacting with it.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul/li[contains(., 'Brussels (BRU)')]")));
```

2.Use findElements() to get the list of suggested options, then use a loop with contains text check to select the desired option:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul/li"));

for(WebElement option : options) {
  if(option.getText().contains("Brussels (BRU)")) {
    option.click();
    break;
  } 
}
```

3.You can also use explicit indexing to select the first/second etc matching option:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[contains(., 'Brussels (BRU)')][1]")).click();
```

4.Handling the drop down differently for one way vs round trip flight selection.
5.Add assertions to validate correct option was selected.